# Odd error trying to create Forge / Fusion Lifecycle Webhook

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

I'm trying to setup an Autodesk Forge Webhook for FusionLifecycle, but I'm getting the following 503 response:

```
{
  "id" : "2da2763d-ed83-4a70-896f-78d98e5c93f5",
  "status" : 503,
  "code" : "INTEGRATION_ERROR",
  "detail" : [ "Authorize-Non-ACM failed and fallback failed." ]
}
```

Can anyone provide feedback on what this means?

Comment: Could you please provide the full body you are providing for the request?

Comment: hey Adam - I didn't hear for a few days, so I opened a case: 16777350.
I'd rather post the body in there, and I have done so.

Comment: Also worth noting - I am using 3-legged-OAuth. As I read it, that is OK?

Comment: Matt, I am following up with this case 16777350. Will reply you there. yes, as the help mentions, the  webhook supports 3LO oauth.

Comment: FYI: in the case of another user the issue was that they did not provide the X-Tenant header in the request

Comment: @AdamNagy is 3LO supported, though? Would you use x-tenant with 3LO?

Comment: I'm told only 3 legged is supported for lifecycle.

Comment: https://help.autodesk.com/view/PLM/ENU/?guid=WH-TUT1-ACT2